# jQuery: How to show a checkbox value on mouseover (without title attribute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, title

I am pretty new to jQuery and need some help with the following.

I have a HTML page with a large, dynamic number of checkboxes and would like to **show a checkbox' value on mouseover without having to add a title** attribute in the code for each of them.

Also, the value of a checkbox can be different to the text that is shown next to her (label). 
The checkboxes are always in a div with the class `'.divCheck'` and the above applies to all checkboxes in these divs (all set up the same way).

So far I have the following which works as intended but seems to be very slow (at least in my test environment).

Is there a faster / better way to achieve this or can this be written different (either the jQuery or the HTML) to make it run faster ?

**My HTML (simplified):**

```
<div class="divCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="checkSingle" id="language1" value="de - German" />
        <label for="language1">de</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="checkSingle" id="language2" value="en - English" />
        <label for="language2">en</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="checkSingle" id="language3" value="es - Spanish" />
        <label for="language3">en</label>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$('div.divCheck label').on('mouseover', function(){
    var checkID = $(this).attr('for');
    var checkVal = $('#'+checkID).val();
    $(this).prop('title', checkVal);
});
```

Many thanks for any help, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use an event handler, you can set the title programatically like

```
$('div.divCheck label').attr('title', function(){
    return $(this).prev('input').val()
});
```

```js
$('div.divCheck label').attr('title', function() {
  return $(this).prev('input').val()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divCheck">
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="checkSingle" id="language1" value="de - German" />
  <label for="language1">de</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="checkSingle" id="language2" value="en - English" />
  <label for="language2">en</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="checkSingle" id="language3" value="es - Spanish" />
  <label for="language3">en</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I was looking for ! Will accept as soon as I can. :) One last question: Can I use .prop for the title as well ? I started switching to this a while ago as I thought it is the newer standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `title` attribute of the checkbox to value. By this, you don't need any library/plugin.

```
$(':checkbox').prop('title', function() {
    return $(this).val();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zstupsbc/

Answer (score 1):

a tooltip library such as [qtip](http://qtip2.com) could help you

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding additional libraries where possible but thanks for this.